# x, y, and format string must not be None のエラー

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pythonを始めたばかりの者です。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
def f(x):
    np.sin(x)       
plt.plot(x, f(x), label = 'y')
plt.show()
```

と入力すると、

> ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None

と表示されます。
このエラーはどういう意味でしょうか、また、原因はなんでしょうか？

Comment: 原因としては、関数 `f(x)` が値を戻していないから、になります(`return np.sin(x)` とする必要があります)。

Comment: 補足すると、Pythonでは明示的に `return` しなかった場合関数の返り値は常に `None` になり、このためValueErrorでは`must not be None`（Noneという値を指定してはいけない）というメッセージが表示されています。

Answer (score 1):

原因としては、関数 `f(x)` が値を戻していないから、になります(`return np.sin(x)` とする必要があります)。

補足すると、Pythonでは明示的に `return` しなかった場合、関数の返り値は常に `None` になり、このため ValueError では `must not be None` (= Noneという値を指定してはいけない) というメッセージが表示されています。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54748/x-y-and-format-string-must-not-be-none-%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment58513_54748) と [@PicoSushi さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54748/x-y-and-format-string-must-not-be-none-%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment58518_54748) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*